# I have two windows forms and when i pressed TAB, the cursor in the form 1 textbox should be placed in form2 textbox.Form1 and form 2 are side by side

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two windows forms and when i pressed TAB, the cursor in the form 1 "textbox" should be placed in form2 "textbox". 
NOTE:Form1 and form 2 are side by side

Comment: Do your forms have any other controls beside `TextBox`?

Comment: in form1 i has only one textbox from then the cursor should go to form2 textbox

Comment: It's about control index ..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
//This form contains textBox1
public class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1(){
       InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override bool ProcessTabKey(bool forward){
       if(textBox1.Focused) form2.FocusText();
       base.ProcessTabKey(forward);
    }
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
}
//This form contains textBox2
public class Form2 : Form {
    public Form2(){
       InitializeComponent();

    }
    public void FocusText(){
       textBox2.Focus();
    }
}
```

It's not a complete solution but can help you understand the basic mechanism to change the code meeting your requirement.